# Existence of a power series that converges at exactly one point

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I understand that any power series should converge at one point, namely the center(?) of the series. For instance, $x=a$ in the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n(x-a)^n$

But is there a power series that converges at *exactly* one point? I can't think of any examples myself but think that somehow if we applied ratio test and got radius of convergence 0 we might be able to.

So$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{c_{n+1}(x-a)^{n+1}}{c_n(x-a)^n}|=lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|\frac{c_{n+1}(x-a)}{c_n}|\ge1$$
for any $x\ne a$ for some $c_n$ and $a$, but what could $c_n$ possibly be? Maybe $c_n=n!$ but I'm not sure if that's even a valid series.

Comment: Yes, that $c_n$ will give you what you want.

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n! x^n$ is a formal power series $\in \Bbb{C}[[x]]$ which is a ring and whose most elements don't define functions nor convergent series, away from the obvious map $f(x)\mapsto f(0)$